# Dynamically change the response language of Google Maps API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

By using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[language] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

I can set the response language of **GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate**.

But when i wanna change the response language when app is running, setting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[theOtherLanguage] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Again doesn't work.

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065420/how-can-i-change-the-language-of-google-maps-on-the-run) for the Google Maps API for Javascript, anyone knows the similar solution for the iOS version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the Geocoding API to receive these responses in a different language. See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) for the Reverse Geocoding article, with the `language` parameter a few paragraphs down.

You can make an `NSURLRequest` with the appropriate URL and language parameters. The response is in JSON format, so you should be able to handle this change dynamically within your code.